# Apply request TimeZone to stripes:format tag or set default TimeZone for some Locales

Tags: java, date, timezone, date-format, stripes

The users of my application are global, but most don't have user profiles where to save their preferred TimeZone information, so I'd like to make a best-effort guess instead, based on their language setting.

For example, if using the language selection buttons they have selected en_US, then I would render dates in New York TZ, if en_GB then in London TZ, if de_DE, then in Berlin TZ and so forth.

I'm using the [Stripes Framework](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home) with code like...

```
<stripes:format value="${someDateValue}" formatType="datetime" formatPattern="medium"/>
```

...in a lot of places, and wouldn't want to go through all of them to update to something else (custom tag or whatever). I would also rather avoid [JavaScript AJAX solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone) (mostly because I think they will also cause me to update a lot of stripes:format tags).

Stripes Framework will use default DateFormat for the request Locale, and that is all working (as the date formats change). But all the timezones remain in server TZ (GMT).

So I want some way to set the TimeZone for the default DateFormat-s returned by DateFormat.getDateInstance() and similar before they are returned, but I'm not sure how to do it.

What I tried so far was to set it on the DateFormat instance returned but of course it is returned by-value so it didn't work:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, new Locale("en_US"));
System.out.println(df.getTimeZone().getDisplayName()); // prints Greenwich Mean Time
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(df.getTimeZone().getDisplayName()); // prints Eastern Standard Time
df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, new Locale("en_US"));
System.out.println(df.getTimeZone().getDisplayName()); // prints Greenwich Mean Time again, although if this approach were successful it would print Eastern Standard Time
```

Any ideas how best to approach this?

My plan B would be a custom Stripes tag, and then changing in the many places where I format dates, but before going that route I'd like to check I'm not missing some simple solution (either a Stripes hook, or a way to change it on more basic Java Locale handling level).

Comment: If you're trying to make a "best guess" effort, language is *not* the best way.  There are *multiple* time zones in the US, for example.  You should consider using [jsTimeZoneDetect](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/) which is still a guess, but a bit more accurate.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the limitations. But in any case, the question is not about how to best determine the TZ to use (btw jsTimeZoneDetect seems a nice solution, thanks for the link), but how to best apply it to dates rendered by the Stripes framework.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about that framework to assist further.  In general though, many frameworks make it difficult to set timezone globally and you have to pass it on each call.  There are some exceptions to that rule though.  I'm not sure about Stripes.

Comment: This one takes the timezone from the request locale (which I change). Hence my thinking is that if I can change the default timezone for a number of Locales, that automagically solves the problem. So in some sense it is not just a Stripes framework question, but also a "can Java date/i18n be parametrized like this" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented it this way and it appears to work fine:

- Custom Stripes FormatterFactory which adds a custom DateFormatter
- DateFormatter gets Timezone offset from the session, having obtained the session from ThreadLocal, and uses it to adjust the DateFormat used to render the Date
- Interceptor stores the timezone offset from the session into the ThreadLocal
- JQuery AJAX invocation on page to submit the JavaScript-obtained timezone offset to the backend where it gets stored in the session

Answer (score 0):

User's timezone offset is not carried on HTTP header. Generally there are two approaches:

1. Create a user profile with time zone setting allowing user to set it
2. Automatically detect the timezone using javascript's Date object `getTimezoneOffset()` and post it to the server using ajax. Search the web for example on this.

Or you can do combination of both

Comment: Yes, I'm doing all that. I'm determining that the user has to show German or UK or whatever locale just fine. It is the TimeZones which are the issue.

Comment: Changed my answer to address client's timezone offset detection

Comment: To clarify your edited answer, I don't have a problem in DECIDING which TimeZone to show for the user (in particular I want to pick a particular TZ per Locale and use that for all users using that Locale).

I do have a problem with getting the DateFormat that Stripes uses to render the stripes:format tag actually using that TimeZone to render the date.

Comment: Locale isn't conceptually associated with timezones. For example country like USA has one locale but comprises of 4 timezones. You will need to manually create a Locale -> timezone map. Generally the better approach is detect the timezone from user's PC

Comment: A large part of the question remains valid even assuming I'm detecting the timezone from user's PC.